# jQuery autocomplete with multiple line breaks

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete to fill out multiple fields when an item is selected. Everything works well unless there is a page break in any of the data. So, here is the jquery example code:

```
var equipment = [
{ id: "3",
  label: "Custom Name 3",
  text: "Some text without line break"
},
{ id: "4",
  label: "Custom 4",
  text: "Some text WITH
line break"
}
];

$( "#equipment" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: equipment,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#equipment" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#equipment" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#id" ).val( ui.item.id );
        $( "#text" ).html( ui.item.text ).text();
        return false;
      }
})
```

And the html:

```
<input id="equipment" name="name">
<textarea id="text" name="text" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Due to the line break in the 'text', I get the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" in that line. I tried using jQuery.data with the same outcome.

How can I fix this error without getting rid of all line breaks?

Comment: Something I did not include in the examples is that id, label and text are pulled from a database with PHP... My bad. Searching for some other stuff I came across json_encode, which solved the issue. Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naeqrbxv/5/). If you replace your line breaks with '\n', it works.

You need to escape the line break in the data before forming the Javascript object (`equipment`) from the data.

Answer (score 1):

For line break you need to add `\n` in text

```
text: "Some text without\nline break"
```

instead of

```
text: "Some text without line break"
```

Try this :|

```js
var equipment = [
{ id: "3",
  label: "Custom Name 3",
  text: "Some text without\nline break"
},
{ id: "4",
  label: "Custom 4",
  text: "Some text WITH\nline break"
}
];

$( "#equipment" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: equipment,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    $( "#equipment" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#equipment").val( ui.item.label );
    $("#id").val( ui.item.id );
    $("#text").html( ui.item.text ).text();
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="equipment" name="name">
<textarea id="text" name="text" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
```